# Recursion of a string with 2 specific start and end point

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am stuck on the assignment which require to write a recursion method to return everything between 2 specific points.
For example, if the input is "javascript" with "v" as start point and "i" as end point, we have to return "ascr"

```
public static String getmiddle(String s, char start, char end) {
    if (s.charAt(0)!=start) {
        getmiddle(s.substring(1), start, end);  
    }

    str = str.substring(1);

    if (str.charAt(0) != end) {
        return s.substring(0,1) + getmiddle(s.substring(1), start, end);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is what I did. The first if method I try to remove the first part before the start point, but I couldn't figure out my 2nd part.

Comment: Idk why you included recursion in the title, this does not require it. All you have to do is iterate over each character in the string, cut it when you hit the start point letter, take the tail. Then iterate over the tail until you reach the end point letter, cut the string and fetch the head.

Comment: I figured we could do it the easier way but the assisngment require me to do with recursion

Comment: Any iteration can be refactored into being a recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

public static String getmiddle(String s, char start, char end) {

```
if (s.charAt(0) != start && s.charAt(s.length() - 1) != end) {

    return getmiddle(s.substring(1, s.length() - 2), start, end);

} else if (s.charAt(0) != start) {
    return getmiddle(s.substring(1), start, end);
} else if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) != end) {
    return getmiddle(s.substring(0, s.length() - 2), start, end);

} else {
    return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is confusing, since there is not necessarily one way to derive the data.

One approach is to write your control-flow, as though all conditions have already been met.
Which is the complete opposite of just basic control-flow.

The following method will return `ascr` for `javascript`, using `v` and `i`.

```java
public static String getmiddle(String s, char start, char end) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == start && s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == end)
        return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    else if (s.charAt(0) != start)
        s = getmiddle(s.substring(1), start, end);
    else if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) != end)
        s = getmiddle(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1), start, end);
    return s;
}
```

Your code deviated at the following conditional-statement, `if (str.charAt(0) != end)`.

You would want to be checking the last character, here, `s.length() - 1`, as opposed to the first, at `0`.